# How to default the font color picker to be black in Word

Tags: microsoft-word

How do I make the font color picker to be default to be black. it's red every time I open the Word application ?

I am not trying to understand how to set the default color of font to be black. (That can be done via defaults from the format font menu)

Why?  When we copy and paste from web browsers, the font color is non-black and I am trying to avoid multiple clicks.

[image]

In this - the "A" - I want that to be black when I open the app / executable. Windows or Mac would work for me.

Answer (score 0):

Click on Home-
the font dialog launcher(it's on the very bottom right of the font section on the ribbon)-
select your color-
click set as default.

Comment: this allows the font color to be changed for a doc. I am asking how to change the picker color to be different than red. (the actual widget)